# UIAlertController dismiss button issue

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I am currently having an issue with the UIAlertController dismiss button. Everytime i select the done button it should check the case and then if the case is met, display the UIAlertController. However the issue I'm facing is when the alert comes up, and I select the dismiss button, and then i select the done button again there are two dismiss buttons, and every time I select done another dismiss button gets added.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Enter Information In All Fields", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Ale

 func doneButtonSelected(){
    if (doctorName.text == "" || doctorEmail.text == "" || doctorNumber.text == ""){
        print("This is empty")

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else{

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you declared `let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Enter Information In All Fields", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)` as global and inside `doneButtonSelected` function, you are adding a `Dismiss` button that's why every time you call the function, it append a `Dismiss` button. Bring your alertController inside the function

```
@IBAction func doneButtonSelected(sender: UIButton) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Enter Information In All Fields", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    if (doctorName.text == "" || doctorEmail.text == "" || doctorNumber.text == ""){
        print("This is empty")

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else{

    }
}
```